# Find the equation of the straight lines through the origin each of which makes an angle of $\alpha$ with $y=x$.

Tags: calculus, geometry

> Find the equation of the straight lines through the origin each of which makes an angle of $\alpha$ with $y=x$.

*Below is my attempt*

Let the lines be $l_1,l_2$.
Since $l_1$ makes an angle $\alpha$ with $y=x$ so it makes an angle of $(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha)$ with $x$-axis

And the line $l_2$ makes an angle $(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha)$ with $x-axis$.

So the equations of two lines are $y_1=\tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha)x,y_2=(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha)x$,

*But how to find the common equation representing the two lines*?

Comment: Those equations aren’t quite right: you left out the $x$’s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common equation can be found by writing the two equations in the form $mx-y=0$ and multiplying them together. Any points that satisfy *either* of the two equations also satisfy their product.

Just to join in the fun, here’s another way to attack this problem. The equations of the lines that make an angle of $\alpha$ with the $x$-axis are $y\pm x\tan\alpha=0$, so their common equation is $(y+x\tan\alpha)(y-x\tan\alpha)=0$, or $y^2=x^2\tan^2\alpha$. Now rotate this through an angle of $\pi/4$ by making the substitutions† $x\mapsto(y+x)$, $y\mapsto(y-x)$: $$(y-x)^2 = (y+x)^2\tan^2\alpha \\ 
y^2-2xy+x^2 = (y^2+2xy+x^2)\tan^2\alpha \\ 
(x^2+y^2)(1-\tan^2\alpha) = 2xy(1+\tan^2\alpha).$$ This can be further simplified, if desired, by using one of the double-angle cosine formulas: $$(x^2+y^2)(1-\tan^2\alpha) = 2xy(1+\tan^2\alpha) \\
(x^2+y^2){1-\tan^2\alpha \over 1+\tan^2\alpha} = 2xy \\
(x^2+y^2)\cos{2\alpha} = 2xy.$$

---

† Strictly speaking, there should be a factor of $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ in this transformation, but this common denominator can be factored out at the end and omitting it reduces clutter in the calculations. Geometrically, a uniform scaling maps lines through the origin onto themselves, so multiplying through by a non-zero constant doesn’t change anything.

Answer (score 3):

The common equation representing the two lines would be :

$$(y-x\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{4}+\alpha))(y-x\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-\alpha)) = 0$$

You can expand to get an equation of pair of straight lines.

Comment: It’s worth expanding $\tan\left(\frac\pi4\pm\alpha\right)$ to get rid of the $\frac\pi4$.

Answer (score 2):

The angle made by straight line is

$$ \pi/4 \pm \alpha $$

So we have the tangent of angle above

$$= \frac { 1+\tan \alpha }{ 1-\tan \alpha },\,  \frac { 1 -\tan \alpha }{ 1+\tan \alpha } $$
and the straight lines required are

$$\frac{y}{x}= \frac { 1+\tan \alpha }{ 1-\tan \alpha },\, \frac{y}{x}=  \frac { 1 -\tan \alpha }{ 1+\tan \alpha } $$
Common equation is

$${\left({\dfrac{y}{x}} \right) }^{\pm 1}= \frac { 1+\tan \alpha }{ 1-\tan \alpha } $$

In polar coordinates simply

$$ \theta = \pi/4 \pm  \alpha $$

for all $r$.

Comment: What happens when $x =0$?  May be better to write it in $y = mx$ form!  But you got the right idea.  ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: Ok in that case, ${\left({\dfrac{y}{x}} \right) }=\left({ \frac { 1+\tan \alpha}{ 1-\tan \alpha }}\right)^{\pm1} ! $

Comment: An elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

In.polar coordinates:

Let $\alpha \not=π/4.$

0) Original line: $\theta_0 = π/4.$

1) Line 1: $\theta_1 = π/4 +\alpha.$

2) Line 2: $\theta_2 = π/4 - \alpha.$

That's it.

Back to Cartesian coordinates:

$x= r\cos(\theta _i);$  $y=r\sin(\theta_i)$,

$i=0,1,2,$ or by eliminating $r:$

$y=\tan(\theta_i) x $,  $i=0,1,2.$

Common equation:

$(y-\tan(\theta_1) x)(y-\tan(\theta_2) x)=0$.